# How to make a select which its options, depends on the other select

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Based on the Material-UI Stepper code, I'd like to implement a select which has options depending on the selected value in another select(in the same react component). I made a switch function:

```js
function getGradeContent(grade: number) {
  switch (grade) {
    case 0:
      return <MenuItem value={0}>Infantil</MenuItem>;
    case 1:
      return (
        <div>
          <MenuItem value={1}>1º Ano</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={2}>2º Ano</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={3}>3º Ano</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={4}>4º Ano</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={5}>5º Ano</MenuItem>
        </div>
      );
    case 2:
      return (
        <div>
          <MenuItem value={6}>6º Ano</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={7}>7º Ano</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={8}>8º Ano</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={9}>9º Ano</MenuItem>
        </div>
      );
    case 3:
      return (
        <div>
          <MenuItem value={10}>1º Ano Médio</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={11}>2º Ano Médio</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={12}>3º Ano Médio</MenuItem>
        </div>
      );
    case 4:
      return <MenuItem value={13}>Técnico</MenuItem>;
    case 5:
      return <MenuItem value={14}>Graduação</MenuItem>;
    case 6:
      return <MenuItem value={14}>Pós-Graduação</MenuItem>;
    default:
      return "Unknown step";
  }
}
```

Then I created a Material Ui Select inside a Formik:

```
export default function ScholarshipForm() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
            actual_school : false,
            school_name : "",
            date_begin : new Date(),
            date_end : "",
            level : 0,
            grade : 0,
        }}
        onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {        
            setTimeout(() => {
                JSON.stringify(values, null, 2);
                console.log(values)
                setSubmitting(false);
            }, 400);
            }}
        validationSchema={validationSchema} 
    >
      {({ values,
          errors,
          touched,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit,
          isSubmitting, }) => (          
          <Form className={classes.root} onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 
            <FormControl id="level" variant="outlined" className= 
               {classes.formControl}>
            <InputLabel id="level">Nivel Escolar</InputLabel>
            <Select
               labelId="level"
               id="level"
               name="level"
               label="Nível Escolar"
               onBlur={handleBlur}
               value={values.level}
               onChange={handleChange}
               aria-describedby="Nivel Escolar"
             >
               <MenuItem value={0}>Infantil</MenuItem>
               <MenuItem value={1}>Fundamental 1</MenuItem>
               <MenuItem value={2}>Fundamental 2</MenuItem>
               <MenuItem value={3}>Médio</MenuItem>
               <MenuItem value={4}>Técnico</MenuItem>
               <MenuItem value={5}>Graduação</MenuItem>
               <MenuItem value={6}>Pós-Graduação</MenuItem>
             </Select>
             <FormHelperText>{(errors.level && touched.level) && errors.level}</FormHelperText>
             </FormControl>
```

This select need to pass `values.level` to the other select, to be applied to that funcion and render the menu item options in this select, here's my failed attempt.

```
<FormControl id="grade" variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
  <InputLabel id="grade">Ano Escolar</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId="grade"
    id="grade"
    name="grade"
    label="Ano Escolar"
    onBlur={handleBlur}
    value={values.grade}
    onChange={handleChange}
    aria-describedby="Ano Escolar"
  >
    {const index = {values.level}; //"Parsing error: Expression expected"
                getGradeContent.map((grade:number, index:number) => {
                    return(
                        {grade}
                    );
                })}
            </Select>
  <FormHelperText>{(errors.level && touched.level) && errors.level}</FormHelperText>
</FormControl>
```

Is there any practical way to solve this?

Comment: you can try directly calling getGradeContent(values.level) . As the getGradeContent is a function and not array the getGradeContent.map won't work.

Comment: This worked in the cases which has only one option "graduação" for example. However when I choose "Ensino Fundamental 2" and try to submit i got this warning.
"A component is changing a controlled input of type hidden to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your can't return MenuItems wrapped in div tag for the second select as it is not the structure that is defined in Material React.

- You can create a map of items that has keys as first Select MenuItem values.
- The second select MenuItems data can be the map values .
- Then you can get the data to create the second select from the Map which is an array.
- This array can be looped to create MenuItems

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-qqsx5